# Save file after forgetting to open as root / sudo vi

Tags: linux, sudo, vim, su, vi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [vim re-edit as root](https://serverfault.com/questions/22558/vim-re-edit-as-root)

I could have sworn I saw this question asked. But after looking though every search result for "vi" I'm stumped/lazy.

I've opened a file, made an edit and now I realize it's read only and I've opened it as non-root me.

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/22558/vim-re-edit-as-root

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
:w !sudo tee "%"
```

I first saw it on [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/1204/save-a-file-you-edited-in-vim-without-the-needed-permissions). The quotes are only necessary if the file path contains spaces.

Answer (score 2):

i do this occasionally, and if the changes i've made are trivial, i just exit and edit it again as root.

otherwise i save the file to /tmp, and mv/cp it as root to where it really belongs later.  and use chown/chgrp/chmod to fix the ownership/perms.

Comment: Rather than cp/mv and chown etc., you could 'sudo cat tmpfile > realfile && rm -f tmpfile', to keep the ownership and perms of the original but give it new contents.

Answer (score 1):

consider adding this line to your vimrc:

```
" Remaps :SW to sudo save the current file and tell vim to reload it
command SW execute 'w !sudo tee % >/dev/null' | e! %
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://blog.sriunplugged.com/2009/12/how-to-save-file-in-vi-not-opened-with-sudo/ . This is what you want i guess